# What does "queue the hypocrisy" mean?

Tags: meaning

I received a message today:

> ...
>
> Not going to hit you with a whole pitch trying obfuscate the fact i'm
> a recruiter trying to persuade a developer to work in a professional
> environment where there meetings are held in a ball pit and the CEO
> enters down a slide........ **queue the hypocrisy** am I right :D
>
> ...

The expression in bold confused me. I tried googling it and got exactly 5 results which did not clarify the meaning much. I searched in a few online dictionaries (Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com, TheFreeDictionary.com), but none of them contains this expression.

So what does "queue the hypocrisy" mean? And what does it have to do with queues?

Comment: "Cue" is a stage direction.  "Queue" is either an accidental misspelling or an intentional "goof", for humorous effect.

Comment: @HotLicks beat me to it as I was copying a def: ***cue*** 1 a : a signal (as a word, phrase, or bit of stage business) to a performer to begin a specific speech or action.    Most likely this was a *hypercorrection* by your mesage sender.

Comment: I see, this explains why there were so few search results.

Comment: @HotLicks could you post your explanation as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: maybe 'Tu quoque'?

Comment: can you cite the quote in your question?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sure you're right, not only did the sender type the wrong "queue" he also missed out the "to" in "to obfuscate" and  typed the wrong "there". I think I'd choose a different agency!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'queue' was in error:

**cue the hypocrisy**

cue  [free dict](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cue)

> To give a cue to; signal or prompt

As in:

> Cue the **hypocrisy** chorus here; the entire event was protected by armed
>   guards with assault rifles.
>
> The Debate over Supreme Court Nominee Begins — Cue the Hypocrisy [article](https://bernardgoldberg.com/the-debate-over-obamas-supreme-court-nominee-begins-along-with-the-hypocrisy/)

In my research i did find that some (Americans especially) frequently 'try' to use cue and queue interchangeably.  One could argue (not me) that it would be reasonable to arrange or organize a procession of hypocrites into a queue, but one could not queue up a chorus.